# How to group nested array of objects mongoldb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I m new to MongoDB, I have written nested lookup with unwinds. now I got the result from my query but I m not able to group these records together, can anyone please help me to solve this. I m stucked here.

Bellow is the query

```
let locations = await UserOtherInformation.aggregate([
            { $match: { user_id: user._id } },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$locations",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$locations.sublocations",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$locations.sublocations.blocks",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$locations.sublocations.blocks.lines",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$locations.sublocations.blocks.lines.stations",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
            },
            {$project : {"locations.locationId": 1,"locations.sublocations.sublocationId":1, "locations.sublocations.blocks.blockId":1 , "locations.sublocations.blocks.lines.lineId":1 , "locations.sublocations.blocks.lines.stations":1 }},
            {   
                $lookup: {
                    from: Location.collection.name,
                    let : { locationId : "$locations.locationId", sublocationId: "$locations.sublocations.sublocationId", block: "$locations.sublocations.blocks.blockId",  line: "$locations.sublocations.blocks.lines.lineId", station :"$locations.sublocations.blocks.lines.stations"},
                    pipeline : [
                        { $match : { $expr : { $eq : ["$_id", "$$locationId"]}}},
                        {
                            $lookup :{
                                from : Sublocation.collection.name,
                                pipeline: [
                                    { $match : { $expr : { $eq : ["$_id", "$$sublocationId"]}}},
                                    {
                                        $lookup :{
                                            from : Block.collection.name,
                                            pipeline: [
                                                { $match : { $expr : { $eq : ["$_id", "$$block"]}}},
                                                {
                                                    $lookup :{
                                                        from : Line.collection.name,
                                                        pipeline: [
                                                            { $match : { $expr : { $eq : ["$_id", "$$line"]}}},
                                                            {
                                                                $lookup :{
                                                                    from : Station.collection.name,
                                                                    pipeline: [
                                                                        { $match : { $expr : { $eq : ["$_id", "$$station"]}}},
                                                                        { $project: { name: 1, number: 1 } }
                                                                    ],
                                                                    as: "stations"
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            { $project: { name: 1, bu:1, stations: 1 } }
                                                        ],
                                                        as: "lines"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                { $project: { name: 1,lines: 1 } }

                                            ],
                                            as: "blocks"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    { $project: { name: 1,blocks: 1 } }
                                ],
                                as: "sublocations"
                            }
                        },
                        { $project: { name: 1, emp_id:1, shift: 1, sublocations: 1 } }
                    ],
                    as: "locations"
                }
            },
])
```

I m getting bellow result from above query

**Result:**

```
"data": [
        {
            "_id": "5ee363682db2e7eed01226b8",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ed90afc9a3c543ad06cd180",
                    "name": "Location2",
                    "sublocations": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5edf4d8cacc40a2b89e47b86",
                            "name": "Pimpri",
                            "blocks": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5edf4d93acc40a2b89e47b87",
                                    "name": "A",
                                    "lines": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5edf4e40acc40a2b89e47b8b",
                                            "name": "2",
                                            "bu": "CV",
                                            "stations": [
                                                {
                                                    "_id": "5ee2713e9c4119ab5372e399",
                                                    "name": "Station1",
                                                    "number": "1"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ee363682db2e7eed01226b8",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ed90afc9a3c543ad06cd180",
                    "name": "Location2",
                    "sublocations": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5edf4d8cacc40a2b89e47b86",
                            "name": "Pimpri",
                            "blocks": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5edf4d93acc40a2b89e47b87",
                                    "name": "A",
                                    "lines": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5edf4e40acc40a2b89e47b8b",
                                            "name": "2",
                                            "bu": "CV",
                                            "stations": [
                                                {
                                                    "_id": "5ee36351eece235ba27cdbf7",
                                                    "name": "Station2",
                                                    "number": "1"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ee363682db2e7eed01226b8",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ee3520302cf9c47aa86c13c",
                    "name": "Pune",
                    "sublocations": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5ee3523402cf9c47aa86c13d",
                            "name": "Pimpri",
                            "blocks": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**Expected Result**

```
"data": [
        {
            "_id": "5ee363682db2e7eed01226b8",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ed90afc9a3c543ad06cd180",
                    "name": "Location2",
                    "sublocations": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5edf4d8cacc40a2b89e47b86",
                            "name": "Pimpri",
                            "blocks": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5edf4d93acc40a2b89e47b87",
                                    "name": "A",
                                    "lines": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5edf4e40acc40a2b89e47b8b",
                                            "name": "2",
                                            "bu": "CV",
                                            "stations": [
                                                {
                                                    "_id": "5ee2713e9c4119ab5372e399",
                                                    "name": "Station1",
                                                    "number": "1"
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                    "_id": "5ee36351eece235ba27cdbf7",
                                                    "name": "Station2",
                                                    "number": "1"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            "_id": "5ee363682db2e7eed01226b8",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ee3520302cf9c47aa86c13c",
                    "name": "Pune",
                    "sublocations": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5ee3523402cf9c47aa86c13d",
                            "name": "Pimpri",
                            "blocks": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Nesting order :

Location, Sublocation, Block, Line, Station each is array of objects

Comment: Your document model looks very relational for a document database  You might be better rethinking how you've modeled your document as that query is immense!

Comment: But I m able to retrieve the data but grouping I m not able to do now